# Interactive Legend using datavisualization chart

Tags: c#, charts

this is my first post here and I am a newbie so this may require more back and forth so I apologize in advance.

I have a legend with all of my different series which each represent a different set of points that I would like to be able to make visible and not visible by clicking on each item on the legend.

From what I have seen, you cannot make a legend event.

My plot is a point plot and here is some of my code, though I don't know if this is very informative

```
chart1.Series.Add(itemChecked.ToString());

          chart1.Series[itemChecked.ToString()].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;



            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                //one = xVals[i];
                chart1.Series[itemChecked.ToString()].Points.AddXY(xVals[i], YVals[i]);
            }
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = chart1.Series[itemChecked.ToString()];
```

Thanks for the time!

Comment: I don't think you can do this without listening to the control's "onclick" and checking where it was clicked, but I don't know much about the Chart control. Maybe a 3rd party chart control?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will look into the "onclick" and keep digging